Total number of ways to paint a cube of six colours
I came across this question recently but couldn't satisfy myself with a good explanation.
Please provide an explanation
The number of distinct ways of painting six faces of a cube with six different colours (one on each face) is K, then value of K is?
I considered two opposite faces like choose one face color in 6 ways and the for the opposite you have 5 choices but there is always a doubt if there are any duplicates or some case being left out.
or considering all faces color one by one? but still loads of doubts>

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

@JoséCarlosSantos edit made

@JaapScherphuis it does

If you have a specific cube and you count the ways you can orient it there are $6$ ways you can chose a top face, and once the top face is chosen there are $4$ ways you can choose a front face. So that is $24$ ways to orient a specific cube. So if you can figure out how many ways to paint where orientation does matter, you divide by $24$ to get the number of ways where it doesn't matter.
